# Zend Framework mobile version

Tags: php, zend-framework, mobile, wurfl

Hi i tried to convert my zend application to mobile version using Wurfl plugin causing error.
the errors that appear is:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Unable to resolve plugin "useragent"; no corresponding plugin with that name' in /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:330 Stack trace: #0 /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(380): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResource('useragent') #1 /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(392): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResources() #2 /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResourceNames() #3 /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #4 /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #5 /var/www/myapp/public/index.php(25): Zend_Application->bootstrap() #6 {main} thrown in /opt/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 330

my application.ini config for wurfl is:

resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.1/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"

so confuse need help !!!

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting this error - 'Unable to resolve plugin "useragent"
Why don't you try out the solution mentioned in this question.. it also deals with this "useragent" plugin error -
[Exception while setting up the wurfl in zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983330/exception-while-setting-up-the-wurfl-in-zend)

take a look at this post too - [Errors when implementing WURFL with Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301637/errors-when-implementing-wurfl-with-zend)

Comment: Hi the solution not working also, my current zend framework version is 1.11, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have given the steps implementing the mobile layout using zend in this [link](https://dineshkumarm.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/find-device-type-using-zend-framework/)

Kindly check

Comment: Hi the solution not working also, my current zend framework version is 1.11, but still not working